# URLImage not always loading

Tags: codenameone

When using URLImage with my code without the line Label lb=new Image(img) I'm only lucky to get the image from webserver from time to time (no request is sent looking in network monitor). When I have this 'false' label I get the image everytime.

Is'nt there a way I can make sure image is loaded every time without this false label?
And a bonus question: is there a way to see when picture have been loaded? or an event for it?

My code:

```
        ryd_storage("skytteimage", true);
        EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(Image.createImage(CN.getDisplayWidth(),CN.getDisplayWidth(), 0xf0f00000), false);
        URLImage img;
        String hurl="https://frederikssund-bueskydning.dk/medlemmer/profil/" +pc;
        img = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "skytteimage",hurl, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL);
        img.fetch();
        Label lb=new Label(img);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URLImage` is meant to be seamless. It's fetched with the purpose of showing not with the purpose of download alone and in that regard it would be sub-optimal as it's asynchronous. It doesn't provide any events (again seamlessness is key).

I'm assuming you just want to download an image to storage which can be done with `ConnectionRequest`:

```
ConnectionRequest cr = new ConnectionRequest(imageUrl, false);
cr.downloadImageToStorage(imageStorageFileName, img -> {
    // you will get an img object here and it's cached in the file system
});
```

Comment: Thx just what I need